# Duplicating PDF file by variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a project and I've ran into a brick wall.

We have a text file which has a numeric value and pdf file name. If the value is 6 we need to print 6 copies of the PDF. I was thinking of creating X copies of the PDF per line then combining them after. I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do it but was wondering if anyone else has another idea.

```
DATA
1,PDF1    
2,PDF5    
7,PDF2    
923,PDF33
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific or show the code you have so far?

Comment: I don't have any code yet as I'm still trying to best approach for this. I'm trying to create X copies of a PDF file. If you look at the data snippet above, line 3(7,PDF2). I want to create 7 copies of PDF2

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the python CSV module to read in your data into two variables, `numCopies` and `filePath` https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

You can then just use

```
for i in range(1, numCopies):
  shutil.copyfile(filePath, newFilePath)
```

or something along those lines.

If you want to physically work with the PDF files I'd recommend the pyPdf module.

Comment: You're going to need to use `range(1, numCopies+1)` or better yet, `range(numCopies)`.